# Dart program execution is not in order

Tags: flutter, dart

In my program I use 2 large json files locally.

My program works, but when I increase the size of the jsons the order of the prints in the console does not arrive any more in the order and seem to be mixed at the end.
How can we be sure that everything is executed correctly?

```
...
children: <Widget>[
_buildDistance(),
_buildAltitudePosition(),
_buildAltitudeObjectif(),
SizedBox(height: 100),
RaisedButton(
  child: Text(
    'Calculer',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
        return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();

    userDifferenceAltitude = userAltitudeObjectif - userAltitudePosition;

    // Function which searches for all the charges which correspond to my distance and classifies them in the order of height
    // Return a load map list
    List searchCharges(int userDistance) {
        var result = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];

        // Create a list with the load which is the distance closest to the userDistance and which is lower
        final filteredCharge = chargesJson
            .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
            .fold(<int, Map<String, dynamic>>{},
                (Map<int, Map<String, dynamic>> map, element) {
                final type = element['type'] as int;

                // If the type of charge is not entered,I enter it
                // If the type exists then I replace it by the highest distance but less than userDistance
                if ((element['distance'] as int) <= userDistance) {
                    if (!map.containsKey(type) || (map[type]['distance'] as int) < (element['distance'] as int)) {
                        map[type] = element;
                    }
                }

                return map;
            })
            .values
            .toList();

        for(int i = 0; i < filteredCharge.length; i++){
            int initialBond         = filteredCharge[i]['bond'];
            int initialDistance     = filteredCharge[i]['distance'];
            int initialHausse       = filteredCharge[i]['hausse'];
            int differenceDistance  = userDistance - initialDistance;
            double updateHausse     = initialHausse - ((initialBond / 100) * differenceDistance);

            // I update my object with distance and hausse
            filteredCharge[i]['hausse']       = updateHausse.round();
            filteredCharge[i]['distance']     = userDistance;
        }

        // Keep the object that has the closest rise to 1100
        switch (filteredCharge.length) {
            case 0:
                // no result
                break;

            case 1:
                // one result
                result = filteredCharge;
                break;

            default:
                // Several results I have to sort
                // I have to look who is closest to the 1100 rise
                // For this I compare the value in absolute and I enter it in value

                for(int i = 0; i < filteredCharge.length; i++){
                    int updatedHausse             = filteredCharge[i]['hausse'];
                    int differenceHausseAbsolute  = (1100 - updatedHausse).abs();
                    filteredCharge[i]['absHausse']          = differenceHausseAbsolute;
                }

                // I rearrange the order to have the smallest upside difference first
                filteredCharge.sort((a, b) => (a['absHausse']).compareTo(b['absHausse']));

                result = filteredCharge;
        }
        return result;
    }

    // List which keeps the charges which correspond to my need
    // I use it if I ever have to switch
    List selectedAllCharge = searchCharges(userDistance);

    // My result is the first
    Map selectedCharge = selectedAllCharge.first;

    // function that gives me the values ​​around
    List searchEncadrementDistanceForCharge(Map selectedCharge) {
        int selectedChargeNumber = selectedCharge['type'];
        var result = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];

        //I keep object who have the same type of my selectedCharge
        List altitudesJsonForCharge = altitudesJson.where((c) => c['type'] == selectedChargeNumber ).toList();
        // If I have results
        if(altitudesJsonForCharge.length != 0) {

            // I look if I have a distance values = userDistance
            List distanceEgale = altitudesJsonForCharge.where((a) => a['distance'] == userDistance).toList();
            // If I have I enter this
            if(distanceEgale.length > 0){
                result.add(distanceEgale.first);
            }else{
                // I have no equality
                // I sort the list to have all the objects that have a lower distance
                List allDistancesInferior = altitudesJsonForCharge.where((a) => a['distance'] < userDistance).toList();

                // I sort the list to have all the objects that have a greater distance
                List allDistancesSuperior = altitudesJsonForCharge.where((a) => a['distance'] > userDistance).toList();

                // I enter the result in my list
                if (allDistancesInferior.isNotEmpty) {
                    // I enter the lower value
                    result.add(allDistancesInferior.last);
                }
                if (allDistancesSuperior.isNotEmpty) {
                    // I enter the higher value
                    result.add(allDistancesSuperior.first);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    List encadrementDistance = searchEncadrementDistanceForCharge(selectedCharge);

    print(encadrementDistance.length);
  },
),
],
```

when I print all my values, in the middle of the print of "**allDistanceInferior**", I have the final print of "**encadrementDistance.length**" which appears with the print of "**allDistancesSuperior**"

I'm new in Dart and Flutter, how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Dart is an asynchronous language.
It means it will not wait for the end of a function/method.

All you have to do is have functions return a Future and call the function with await.

You can use a Future builder or make use of setState and StatefulWidget to update gui when you know all your calculations are finished.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My code is in a Future builder for load my json.

Comment: @user2895656 for example "List searchCharges(int userDistance) {" should be defined as "Future<List> searchCharges(int userDistance) async {" and call it using "await searchCharges(...)"